# How to find MQ listener port on AIX?

Tags: listener, ibm-mq

I have created a queue manager using
    `crtmqm <Queue_manager_name>`
and then started it using
    `strmqm <Queue_manager_name>`
I want to find on which port does this Queue manager listen? Is there some command to see this?
    `ps -ef|grep runmqlsr`
and
    `DISPLAY LSSTATUS(*)`
give nothing.
Can it be that the queue manager is not listening to any port?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to create a listener after starting the queue manager. The `crtmqm` command creates default listener for all the supported transport types. It is recommended you create your own listener. Do the following in a MQSC shell

```
DEF LISTENER(MYMQLISTENER)  TRPTYPE(TCP) +
    CONTROL(QMGR)            PORT(1414) +
    REPLACE

START LISTENER(MYMQLISTENER)
```

The above command creates a listener with a name `MYMQLISTENER` transport and the listens on port 1414. The  `CONTROL(QMGR)` directs the queue manager to start the listener when queue manager starts and stop it when queue manager goes down. The `START LISTENER` command starts the listener. You also have `STOP LISTENER` MQSC command to stop the listener.

Once you create and start the listener, you can then issue DISPLAY LSSTATUS command to display the listener status.

Comment: Although the above tells HOW to add a listener, it doesn't address the question of HOW to get the port that it's running on.

Comment: Also, manually started listeners ... not helpful.  Have them start with the queue manager, then support doesn't have to figure out why stuff isn't working.

Answer (score 3):

Mostly I use `MQSC` command `DISPLAY LSSTATUS(*) ALL`. It display all necessary details to me along with port number.

Here sample output:

```
LISTENER(SYSTEM.LISTENER.TCP.1)         STATUS(RUNNING)
PID(15961)                              STARTDA(2014-02-04)
STARTTI(12.11.10)                       DESCR( )
TRPTYPE(TCP)                            CONTROL(MANUAL)
IPADDR(*)                               PORT(2011)
BACKLOG(100)
```